# Doctrine: Cannot get entity from proxy after merge

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, proxy, deserialization

I'm getting a json containing an entity A(associated to entity B) in a post request. I deserialize it and then merge and flush it. When I check the B property from A, I get a proxy. This is puzzling, since the association with B is annotated with the EAGER fetch mode.

I even refreshed entity A but still its B member keeps returning a proxy for B. The only change is this time the proxy is marked as initialized.

Any tips?

Comment: And what is the issue with that?

Comment: Proxys include closures and I'm trying to use the entity for a [json-api serializer](https://github.com/nilportugues/php-json-api) which refuses to use closures as members of the object to be serialized.